# powertools spartacus B2B site in CX 2005 verinot able to add product into the cart

Tags: spartacus-storefront

i have setup OOTB Powertools B2B in CX 2005 with spartacus storefront . but while adding the product into the cart i am getting this error.

```
Error: 
"message" : "It's not allowed to execute this call from the current channel",
      "type" : "AccessDeniedError"
```

The add to cart post url is :
https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/powertools-spa/users/anonymous/carts/a6ea625f-6ee4-4b01-9b6a-26a4bfbbe674/entries?code=3755213&qty=1&lang=en&curr=USD

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aT2j.png)

1. i have already added the cors params in local.properties and ran the impex as well , which is mentioned in the https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/cors/
2. electronics store is working fine only powertools has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We made some changes to Powertools in our sample data in 1.3. That said, Powertools is still not fully supported. We are moving in this direction with the 2+ releases.

Please see this disclaimer for Powertools https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/release-information/#b2b-storefront-features.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute!

Here in my project I am instantiating a Spartacua TUA (Telco Utilities Accelerator)

I've been having this problem "It's not allowed to execute this call from the current channel" and in my case the solution was to review the property "api.compatibility.b2c.channels" which was with the B2B value for the B2C store. I changed the value and it worked correctly again!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).